# Column loop and update another column with COUNT() value from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my table `events`

```
event name  countBus
ev12  test  NULL
ev16  paris NULL
```

and table `klient`

```
event name  bus
ev12  bob   True
ev12  Alice True
ev12  John  False
ev16  Tom   True
ev16  Peter False
```

What I'm trying to do is to loop through all rows of table `events` and update amount of rows that is found in table `klient` for particular event and `bus=True`. Then back update that value to particular row in table `events` column `countBus`.

Output of table `event` would be

```
ev12  test  2
ev16  paris 1
```

I'm sorry for not providing my attempt as I don't even know where to start.

Thanks for spending your free time on this.

Comment: Are you building data warehouse tables? Otherwise you would usually not store information reduntly which can be got from present data already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could di it with a sub-select like this:

```
UPDATE events
SET countBus = (SELECT count(*) 
                FROM klient k 
                WHERE events.event = k.event 
                AND k.bus = 'True')
```

Or with a join, like this:

```
UPDATE e
SET countBus = t.countBus2
FROM events e
INNER JOIN (SELECT event, bus, COUNT(*) countBus2
            FROM klient
            WHERE bus = 'True'
            GROUP BY event, bus) AS t
ON e.event = k.event
```

Comment: Your first update script isn't valid with the alias, it needs to be: `UPDATE e SET countBus(SELECT.....) FROM events e` and your second one should just start `UPDATE e` without events

Answer (score 1):

So to break this up and explain it a little you need to do two things really:

1. Find a query that will give you the count per event
2. Write an update query based on the logic of the query in step 1

**Query to get the count per event**

```
select e.event, e.name, count(bus)
from klient k
inner join events e on k.event = e.event 
where k.bus = N'True'
group by e.event, e.name
```

Working Sample: [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1d9e2/4)

**The Update Query**

```
update events
set countBus = (select count(bus)
                from klient k
                where k.event = events.event and k.bus = N'True')
-- view the results
select * from events
```

Working Sample: [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1d9e2/6)